# Java : Parsing a Json formated String to Java

Tags: java

I do a Action on Middle ware and if its success i get the Value as

```
String result = ["RESULT","DELETE","OK"]
```

And in Case if the Operation is Failed i get the resposne as

```
String result = ["RESULT","DELETE","ERROR"]
```

I need to know if the Operation is success Or Fail  so for this i have done this

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String result = "[\"RESULT\",\"DELETE\",\"ERROR\"]";

        if (!result.contains("ERROR")) {
            System.out.println("success");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }

    }
```

This is working fine , but not sure if this has any negative impact / or in cases the code may Fail .

Please suggest if there is a better approach .

Comment: Use a proper library to parse Json. E.g. Jackson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code can fail if, for instance, you get a success message containing `ERROR` (not likely, but can happen).

You should use a library to parse the result into a List/Array, look here on StackOverflow for a ton of solutions for parsing Json Strings to Objects in Java (Jackson is a library to do this, for instance).

You should also validate against a pre-set number of hypothesis, for instance, creating an `enum` for the possible result types, and checking if it's one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use object presentation instead of array here:

```
{
 "RESULT": {
   "operation": "DELETE",
   "status" : "ERROR"
 }
}
```

There is you can find a lot of tools to parse JSON in Java objects:
http://www.json.org/

In other case it will be hard to extend set of codes. E.g.

```
String result = "[\"RESULT\",\"CREATE\",\"USER\", \"LOGIN\", \"ERROR\", \"SUCCESS\"]";
```

Was there error? or user with login ERROR was successfully created?

Answer (score -1):

```
String[] result = {"RESULT","DELETE","OK"};
    if(Arrays.asList(result).contains("OK"))
        System.out.println("Ok");
```

Try Arrays.asList() method to check given arrays contains that element or not.

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to String[]